# jQuery.ajax fails when url is from different server

Tags: jquery, ajax

Why does jQuery.ajax() throw an error with no error message if you use a URL with a dfferent server?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its because of the restriction on cross domain requests implemented in the browser for XMLHttpRequests.  You can get around this by using JSONP as the format, otherwise you'll need a server-side proxy for the request.

Quoting from the [ajax documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) on http://jquery.com

> Note: All remote (not on the same
>   domain) requests should be specified
>   as GET when 'script' or 'jsonp' is the
>   dataType (because it loads script
>   using a DOM script tag). Ajax options
>   that require an XMLHttpRequest object
>   are not available for these requests.
>   The complete and success functions are
>   called on completion, but do not
>   receive an XHR object; the beforeSend
>   and dataFilter functions are not
>   called.

Answer (score 6):

As http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing says:

> **Cross-origin resource sharing (CORS)** is a mechanism that allows a web page to make XMLHttpRequests to another domain.[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) Such "cross-domain" requests would otherwise be forbidden by web browsers, per the same origin security policy. CORS defines a way in which the browser and the server can interact to determine whether or not to allow the cross-origin request.[2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) It is more powerful than only allowing same-origin requests, but it is more secure than simply allowing all such cross-origin requests.

For PHP it is done using **[header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)** function:

```
<?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com");
?>
```

> **CORS** can be used as a modern alternative to the JSONP pattern. While
> JSONP supports only the GET request method, CORS also supports other
> types of HTTP requests. Using CORS enables a web programmer to use
> regular XMLHttpRequest, which supports better error handling than
> JSONP. On the other hand, JSONP works on legacy browsers which
> preclude CORS support. CORS is supported by most modern web browsers.
> Also, whilst JSONP can cause XSS issues where the external site is
> compromised, CORS allows websites to manually parse responses to
> ensure security.
>
> JSONP or "JSON with padding" is a communication technique used in
> JavaScript. It provides a method to request data from a server in a
> different domain, something prohibited by typical web browsers because
> of the same origin policy.

Answer (score 2):

The ajax() method internally uses XmlHttpRequest which obeys the same domain policy http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy. 
The [getJson()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) method can be used instead for making cross domain calls.

I hope this helps,
Bogdan

Answer (score 0):

Because if Same Origin Policy jQuery will not allow this. The best option will be using some proxy server page to get the required pages.