# Is it possible to read xml using jQuery from different domain?

Tags: php, jquery, xml, ajax, xml-parsing

I need to parse a xml file using jQuery from an external domain. How can I do that?

This is my code.

```
$("#mydiv").click(function () {


        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://tester.com/testxml/announcement.xml',
            success: function(data){
                alert( $(data).find('Document:title').text() );
            },
            dataType: 'xml'
        });


    });
```

Comment: Is your domain name listed in the crossdomainpolicy.xml file of targeted domain?

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201429/jquery-ajax-fails-when-url-is-from-different-server

Comment: Do you have access to the code of the second domain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot read cross-domain xml using `Jquery.ajax()`.

However, you could try for [`script-inclusion`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/include-javascript-file-inside-javascript-file) which works cross-domain

Answer (score 1):

You could...

- Use a server side proxy.
- Use YQL.
- If you can access the code of the second server and don't need to support IE7 and below, set up CORS.