# Store data received as answer from jQuery.POST

Tags: jquery

I need to save all the data received as answer from POST function.

```
jQuery.post( url [, data] [, success(data, textStatus, jqXHR)] [, dataType] )
```

If I understand it right, function calls url (something.php) and it respondes with **data**. Is there any way how can I store received data on my HDD ?
Or maybe send received data elsewhere on my server where I can store them in DBS, or anyhow else.

Comment: You would need to store the data using server-side code, such as, within `something.php` if i'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: But I am not able to access server-side. I need to do that as client by parsing recieved data.

Comment: What HDD do you want to store it on? local? on a server?

Comment: mine local. Or send data elsewhere on other server maybe localhost.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.post('/someurl.php',
    {one:'value1',two:'value2'},
    function( response ) { alert(response); } );
```

On someurl.php, you would get these values with:

```
$oneValue = $_POST['one'];
$twoValue = $_POST['two'];

echo '{success:1}';
```

How you save them is then up to the PHP code.

**EDIT**
JavaScript has specific restrictions from being able to access a local computer.  Otherwise any hacker's script would be able to save files to your computer, which we wouldn't want.

You mentioned localhost in your comment above and that sounds like the best approach most likely.  Post to the site, get the response, and then post the response to your localhost server where you do have access to the server side code to be able to save it to your computer. Something like:

```
jQuery.post('/someurl.php', {}, function( data ) { 
    jQuery.post('http://localhost/save.php', data, function() { alert('saved'); ]);
} );
```

Comment: I dont have access to PHP code. It has to be done on client side, or send data on mine server where I can process them.

Comment: You can't do it via client-side code.  You have to have server-side somewhere.  It doesn't have to be PHP...just a page that can handle posted data.  That was the point of the http://localhost/save example above...that you have to post your result to a server that you CAN control.

Comment: Well problem is that javascript does not allow me to call "http://". It wants to stay on same server (just "/something").

Comment: JavaScript wasn't intended for the purpose you're trying, so hitting a lot of roadblocks is expected.  See if this helps with overcoming the cross-site scripting protections: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201429/jquery-ajax-fails-when-url-is-from-different-server

Comment: It is not working for localhost. I am trying now to use greasemonkey to overrdide post function, or just grab the data it provides. No big success so far... Any ideas ? :)

Comment: Sorry, I wouldn't be able to help much more without actually trying to do it, since I've never tried to save data from a server I didn't have access to.