# $.get not working with jQuery

Tags: jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [jQuery.ajax fails when url is from different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201429/jquery-ajax-fails-when-url-is-from-different-server)

I have a code like this on my test page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.get(
        "http://www.google.com",
        function(data) { alert(data); }
    );

});
```

The problem is, that I never get the alert and I don't know why.

Does anybody know what the error could be? Its a simple html page and all other jQuery stuff is working.

Comment: Your Ajax request fails as google is in a different domain without CORS enabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't working for you, because you're trying to perform crossdomain XmlHttpRequest. You might want to check out this [Cross domain mod for jQuery](https://github.com/padolsey/jQuery-Plugins/tree/master/cross-domain-ajax/)

Answer (score 3):

The $.get function in jQuery executes an AJAX request with the HTTP type of GET. Due to [Same origin policy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy), you can't request pages from outside of your domain.

If you need to request pages from another domain, you would need to setup a script hosted on your site to proxy these requests.

Answer (score 2):

If its google.com you are trying to get then it wont work, XHR only works on your own domain. the other site need to have Cross-site XMLHttpRequest enabled.