# Get a CSV from a web service using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-services

I'm trying to use javascript to get a csv from a web service hosted by yahoo. I'm pretty new to javascript and webservices so I really don't know whats wrong.

symbol = CSCO

```
$.ajax({
url: "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=" + symbol+ "&f=price",
type: "GET",
beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/csv");
},
success:OnSuccessCall,
error: OnErrorCall()
});



function OnSuccessCall(response) {
    alert('woo');
}
function OnErrorCall(response) {
    alert('boo');
}
```

Comment: You have an extra closing brace before `OnSuccessCall(response)`

Comment: And it should be `error: OnErrorCall` - without the `()`

Comment: We don't know what's wrong too... you need to tell us what kind of error message you're getting.  However, I'm pretty sure you're dealing with a cross domain issue.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201429/jquery-ajax-fails-when-url-is-from-different-server

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript cannot be used for this purpose because of [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Your own server needs to retrieve the data from finance.yahoo.com which then can be accessed by JavaScript.